# PHP and javascript: pass new Date as json

Tags: javascript, php, json

I utilize google chart table. In DataTable i need a date and for example, the javascript code must be the following:

```
rows: [{c:[{v: 'Mike'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28), f:'February 28, 2008'}]},
```

How can i pass the

```
new Date(2008, 1, 28)
```

as json object from php?

I have done:

```
....
array('v' => "new Date($timeStamp)");
...
$output = json_encode($table);
```

but in the javascript i receive `new Date(2008, 1, 28)` as string and doesn't instantiate new date.

How can i instantiate a new Date()?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be like this: `array('v' => Date($timeStamp));`? Why are you adding quotes and why new operator?

Comment: While it is possible to generate this via PHP, it would be wrong to call it JSON, as JSON does not support embedded function calls nor `new`. Can you show the code where PHP outputs the "JSON" and the context around it (other JavaScript maybe)?

Comment: @Thamizhan i've tried but doesn't work the json_encode

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one in you javascript:

```
var date = eval("new Date(2008, 1, 28)"); // Here should paste the string that you receive.
```

That should eval it.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript object you want to get to is not JSON, as JSON does not allow the `new` keyword, nor the call of a function, like `Date()`.

What you could do, is move away from pure JSON, like this:

```
<?
$timeStamp = time (); // UNIX epoch

$table = array(
    array('v' => 31415926535), // some unique number, that does not occur elsewhere
);
$output = json_encode($table);
// Alter JSON, and now you cannot call it JSON anymore:
$output = str_replace($table[0]['v'], "new Date($timeStamp)", $output);
?>
<script>
    var table = {
        ...
        rows: <?= $output ?>,
        ...
    };
    ...
</script>
```

Make sure the *$timeStamp* is either a number representing a UNIX epoch (like example abopve), or a string, well-formatted for JavaScript to interpret as a date. In the latter case you will need to wrap *$timeStamp* in single quotes.